# In WebStorm, can't navigate from .feature file to step definitions in a nonstandard directory

Tags: cucumber, webstorm, gherkin, cucumberjs

WebStorm doesn't navigate from a `.feature` file to the function declaration in `stepDefinition.js` if the name of the folder is `stepDefinitions`. It works fine if the folder name is `step_definitions`.

Is there a setting in WebStorm that I can change so that it will look for step definitions JS files under `stepDefinitions` and not `step_definitions`?

I am talking about this feature:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/15.0/navigating-from-feature-file-to-step-definition.html?origin=old_help

I would like to stick to the programming standards we have established. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

No, WebStorm can't be configured to look for Cucumber step definitions in a folder other than `step_definitions`. [An issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11505) is filed with JetBrains and it has not been fixed yet. You can vote for it to encourage JetBrains to fix it.

That issue mentions a workaround, which is to make a symlink from your non-standard step definition folder to the standard one.

Comment: OP should accept this answer. It solved the issue for me.